# Problems in rendering using Nine-Patch image in Android SeekBar

Tags: android, rendering, nine-patch, android-seekbar

I am trying to use an Android seekbar with a custom layout, however if I try to set the ProgressDrawable with a layer of Nine-Patch images, to support multiple resolutions, it doesn't work. However if I don't use a Nine-Patch it renders correctly, but gets stretched.
Here's the code I use to programmatically set the progress:

```
mAuxSlideButton.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.seekbar_slidebutton_progress_clip);
```

and this is the `seekbar_slidebutton_progress_clip.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_slidebutton_progressbackground" >
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_slidebutton_progressbar" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Here's two images showing the result and the images used:
[image: Image showing when there's no nine-patch, the Progress and Progress Background below]

[image: Image showing when nine-patch is used, the Progress and Progress Background below]

The only difference is that I selected the image in Android Studio and made the nine-patch by it.

Does anyone know why this happens? I can't use the direct XML because the button is made in run-time, when the conditions are met, otherwise it is a simple button.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nine-Patches work just fine, i have no idea what you mean by `"it doesn't work"`

Comment: In the photos the second is when I use the Nine-Patch, the Progress Background scales just fine, however the Progress it's too small. I don't know why it happens, I wanted it to be like the first image.

Comment: try [this](http://pastebin.com/pdKHCvvd)